# Accessing and changing a txt document while running a windows form in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, file, streamreader

I'm currently teaching myself how to use the Windows Form to interact with an MIRC bot I've also been making. Currently, I have question coming in through the bot and put out to a .txt file, which is then being picked up by the Windows Form.  Currently, my code is working when it pulls the data, but once I create the StreamReader to pull from the text, MIRC becomes unable to modify the file any further while the Windows Form is running.  I've tried putting in Close(), but that didn't do the trick.  here is the code I'm using for the button in Windows Form:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i = 0;
    questionDoc = new StreamReader("questions.txt");
    if (questionDoc.ReadLine() != null)
    {
        fullText = questionDoc.ReadToEnd();
        questionList = fullText.Split('\t');
        for (int j = 0; j < questionList.Length; j++)
        {
            this.label1.Text = questionList[j];
        }
        questionDoc.Close();
    }
    else
        this.label1.Text = "No questions!";
}
```

So currently I can pull the questions, but the txt document can no longer be updated the first time I click that button.  Is there another way around this?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are not closing the file handle if the file is empty so your other application cant write to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the file access using `File.Open()` so that other processes can read and write to it using `FileShare.ReadWrite` ([***MSDN***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Open("questions.txt", FileMode.Open,
       FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)) {
    using (StreamReader questionDoc = new StreamReader(fs)) {
        // do your stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try closing the file even if the first ReadLine() returns null.  Also, make "questionDoc" a variable rather than a field, and dispose it unconditionally, like so:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        i = 0;
        using (var questionDoc = new StreamReader("questions.txt"))
        {
            if (questionDoc != null && questionDoc.ReadLine() != null)
            {
                fullText = questionDoc.ReadToEnd();
                questionList = fullText.Split('\t');
                for (int j = 0; j < questionList.Length; j++)
                {
                    this.label1.Text = questionList[j];
                }
            }
            else
                this.label1.Text = "No questions!";
        }
    }
```

You probably want to add a `try/catch` for an [`IOException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ioexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in case the file is locked by the other application, or is deleted, or something else goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily make a copy of the file and open the copy:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i = 0;
    File.Copy("questions.txt", "questionsCopy.txt", true);
    questionDoc = new StreamReader("questionsCopy.txt");
    if (questionDoc.ReadLine() != null)
    {
        fullText = questionDoc.ReadToEnd();
        questionList = fullText.Split('\t');
        for (int j = 0; j < questionList.Length; j++)
        {
            this.label1.Text = questionList[j];
        }
        questionDoc.Close();
    }
    else
        this.label1.Text = "No questions!";

}
```